# Spring MVC - using FactoryBeans

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, dependency-injection, dependencies

A bean that implements the interface FactoryBean (a pattern to encapsulate interesting object construction logic in a class) 
can be used as a normal bean?

Comment: can you please elaborate a little bit more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To summarize in short:

- Yes you can use a FactoryBean like a normal bean (inject it into other beans for example)
- Additionally the factory bean will create instances (or a singleton instance) of `<T>` on demand, which will be a Spring bean as well. Thus you could also inject an instance of `<T>` into other beans. Spring will create an instance using your factory in this case

The main reason for using custom `FactoryBeans` from the reference documentation:

> The FactoryBean interface is a point of pluggability into the Spring IoC container’s instantiation logic. If you have complex initialization code that is better expressed in Java as opposed to a (potentially) verbose amount of XML, you can create your own FactoryBean, write the complex initialization inside that class, and then plug your custom FactoryBean into the container.

Furhter reading: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.1.7.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-extension-factorybean

Answer (score 0):

A FactoryBean is defined in a bean style, but the object exposed for bean reference (getObject()) is always the object that it creates